# Subset character vector in R

Tags: r, string, subset

I know this is a super easy question but I really don't know what the best (most common) way in R is.
I have a character-vector:

```
> dataframes
[1] "saga/dataframes/isce.log"                          "saga/dataframes/no_filter.csv"                    
[3] "saga/dataframes/sig0.9_iter100_viter50_nb_cv0.csv" "saga/dataframes/sig0.9_iter20_viter50_nb_cv0.csv"
```

And what I want are the entries where no `isce.log` is in the element. So actually the 2nd to 4th.
There are so many options in R to work with character-vector that I'm super confused.
Is this a case for `subset` or maybe for `dplyr`'s `filter` or `str_subset`...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grepl`:

```
dataframes[!grepl("isce.log", dataframes, fixed=TRUE)]

[1] "saga/dataframes/no_filter.csv"
[2] "saga/dataframes/sig0.9_iter100_viter50_nb_cv0.csv"
[3] "saga/dataframes/sig0.9_iter20_viter50_nb_cv0.csv"
```

**Data:**

```
dataframes <- c("saga/dataframes/isce.log",
                "saga/dataframes/no_filter.csv",  
                "saga/dataframes/sig0.9_iter100_viter50_nb_cv0.csv",
                "saga/dataframes/sig0.9_iter20_viter50_nb_cv0.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot:) Really need to learn more about using grep...

Answer (score 4):

Using `str_subset` :

```
stringr::str_subset(dataframes, "isce.log", negate = TRUE)

#[1] "saga/dataframes/no_filter.csv" 
#[2] "saga/dataframes/sig0.9_iter100_viter50_nb_cv0.csv"
#[3] "saga/dataframes/sig0.9_iter20_viter50_nb_cv0.csv"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try:

```
grep("isce.log",dataframes,value=TRUE,invert=TRUE)
```

The option `value=TRUE` returns the value from your vector that matches, and you use `invert=TRUE` to flip..

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Grep really seems the best tool for this. But why would I want to invert it?

Comment: You want the values that don't have "isce.log" ? So it has to be the inverse. If you try ```grep("isce.log",dataframes,value=TRUE)``` you get values that have the pattern

Comment: Of course.... Sorry, didn't have enough coffee yet